# What is $(65!)^2$ congruent to mod $131$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I'm trying to find a solution for the equation $$(65!)^2\equiv x\:(\text{mod}\: 131)$$
I'm given the hint to use Wilson's Theorem which states, that for a prime $p$ we have $(p-1)!\equiv -1\:(\text{mod}\:p)$.

The only thing I've managed to so far is insert my number in Wilson's Theorem: So I get $(130!)\equiv -1\:(\text{mod}\: 131)$. From here on I have no idea what to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Apologies for any english errors.

Comment: More generally, if $n=2k+1$ is an odd number, you can show: $$(n-1)!\equiv (-1)^{k}\left(k!\right)^2\pmod{n}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  in your first comment, you meant $\mod 131$ ?

Comment: Yes, typo, sorry. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
130!
&\equiv130\cdot129\cdots66\cdot65\cdots2\cdot1\mod{131}\\
&\equiv(-1)\cdot(-2)\cdots(-65)\cdot65\cdots2\cdot1\mod{131}\\
&\equiv(-1)^{65}(65!)^2\mod{131}\\
&\equiv-(65!)^2\mod{131}\\
&\equiv-1\mod{131}\\
\end{align}$$
$$\therefore(65!)^2\equiv1\mod{131}$$

Comment: This answer is written "out of order", isn't it? You start with $130!$ and show that it's congruent to $-(65!)^2$, and then you invoke the fact that $130! \cong -1$, and finally you conclude that $-(65!)^2 \cong -1$ and therefore $(65!)^2 \cong 1$. Wouldn't it be easier to follow if you started with $-(65!)^2$, manipulated that into $130!$, and then rewrote that to $-1$?